# How to add a value to an object's array dynamically?

Tags: php

I don't see the wood for the trees, please point me into the right direction.

I've got a mysql query and retrieve the rows as objects. This works fine.
Now, I want to populate an object's array with the values from the database.
This object ($myobject) has several arrays (i.e. $myobject->field_1). These arrays contain (multiple) values for a certain field in various languages, hence it could be sth. like $myobject->field_1['en'][0] = 'value'. Here's what I tried to do:

```
$query = 'SELECT t.id, t.lang, t.val FROM table t';
$result = db_query($query); // custom db layer function
foreach ($result AS $row) {
    $fieldname = 'field_'.$row->id;
    $myobject->$fieldname[$row->lang][] = $row->val;
}
```

The last line is not working. Since I do not know, how many values are already stored for a language, I just want to add ([]) a value to the end of the array.

Which neat trick am I missing?

Comment: Show sample of `$result`

Comment: On line 4, you have a square bracket which doesn't match up.  Is that a typo in your example here, or is that in your code?

Comment: @Zack: Yes, that has been a typo. Just fixed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$query = 'SELECT t.id, t.lang, t.val FROM table t';

$result = db_query($query); // custom db layer function

foreach ($result AS $row) {
    $fieldname = 'field_'.$row->id;
    $myobject->{$fieldname}[$row->lang][] = $row->val;
}
```

Notice the braces around the $fieldname at the last line

Comment: That's it. Thanks, I knew it was something simple like that, I really need some days off. ;)